# Hub and Authority scores: networkx vs igraph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, igraph

I computed hub and authority scores of a simple graph using igraph and networkx and they give me the same results. For example, see below

```
import networkx as nx
from igraph import *
G = nx.DiGraph() 
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'A'), 
                  ('D', 'C'), ('E', 'D'), ('E', 'B'), ('E', 'F'), 
                  ('E', 'C'), ('F', 'C'), ('F', 'H'), ('G', 'A'),  
                  ('G', 'C'), ('H', 'A')]) 
hubs, authorities = nx.hits(G, max_iter = 50, normalized = True) 
edges = [('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'A'), 
                  ('D', 'C'), ('E', 'D'), ('E', 'B'), ('E', 'F'), 
                  ('E', 'C'), ('F', 'C'), ('F', 'H'), ('G', 'A'),  
                  ('G', 'C'), ('H', 'A')]
g = Graph.TupleList(directed=True,edges=edges)
hub_igraph = [g.hub_score()[i]/sum(g.hub_score()) for i in range(len(g.hub_score()))]
```

```
In[1] print(hubs)
Out[1]
{'A': 0.04642540386472174,
 'D': 0.133660375232863,
 'B': 0.15763599440595596,
 'C': 0.037389132480584515,
 'E': 0.2588144594158868,
 'F': 0.15763599440595596,
 'H': 0.037389132480584515,
 'G': 0.17104950771344754}
In[2] print(hub_igraph)
Out[2] 
[0.04642540403219994,
 0.13366037526115376,
 0.1576359944296732,
 0.03738913224642651,
 0.2588144598468665,
 0.1576359944296732,
 0.037389132246426524,
 0.17104950750758036]
```

However, for large graph (2k nodes) that is sparse and almost tree-like, the result is vastly different. I computed the hub/authority score using HITS algorithm and the output for the large graph matches the one from networkx but not the one from igraph. I cannot find the source-code for igraph and hence I am wondering where is the discrepancy coming from.

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is good to know. I think this issue might better be discussed at the [igraph forum](https://igraph.discourse.group), because it hints at a problem of the implementation of `igraph` that should be corrected.

Comment: @VincentTraag Why do you think that the issue lies with `igraph`, not `networkx` (congratulations on securing the funding, btw)? In my experience, Tamas` code is a heck of a lot better than the parts of `networkx` I had a closer look at (which will be more varied as they had more core contributors over the years -- at least in my perception).

Comment: Yes, the problem could also be in `networkx`. But the OP says that (s)he "computed the hub/authority score using HITS algorithm and the output for the large graph matches the one from networkx but not the one from igraph". And thanks, it should speed up development some more!

Comment: I confirm the comment from @Vincent Traag. Since networkx output matches the manual HITS computation, my suspicion lies in igraph. I am happy to be proven wrong. Where can I look at the source code for igraph.hub_score()? Unfortunately, I can't locate it here-https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-pysrc.html#GraphBase.hub_score

Comment: The source code is written in C and is available from https://github.com/igraph/igraph. As stated, please consider posting this to the [igraph forum](https://igraph.discourse.group).

Comment: OP has opened an issue [here](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/306), but has not provided any reproducible example. We can only fix a problem if we can reproduce it. Since at this point it's unclear if there is even an issue, it would have been better to post on the forum (not the issue tracker) as @VincentTraag suggested.

Comment: @ForumWhiner did you post this on [igraph forum](https://igraph.discourse.group/)?